# Magento 2.3.1 - Cannot send email with attachment using template

Tags: magento2, upgrade

This code was working before in M2.1 but it is not working anymore after upgrade as Zend1 is depricated. Can you please suggest how to fix this code.

```
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('order_csv')
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store])
                ->setTemplateVars(
                    [
                        'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()
                    ]
                )
                ->setFrom('general')
                ->addTo('email@gmail.com', 'Name')
                ->addCSVAttachment(file_get_contents($outputFile), $outputFile)
                ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
```

Definition of addCSVAttachment

```
public function addCSVAttachment(
    $body, $filename
) {
     $attachment = new \Zend\Mime\Part($body);
        $attachment->type = 'text/csv';
        $attachment->disposition = \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
        $attachment->encoding = \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
        $attachment->filename = $filename;
    return $attachment;
}
```

Comment: Please try to install this module https://github.com/extait-com/email-attachment

Comment: @KamleshSolanki I have tried the extension, but it is not using template to generate the body of the email. So it is not working in my case

Answer (score 0):

You mail functionality missing this  `->setTemplateVars()`
You call this function addCSVAttachment before send mail and assign the return data to some variable and pass that variable in `->setTemplateVars()` as below shown.

below is just an example

```
$emailTemplateVariables = array();
$emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $variablevalue1;
$emailTempVariables['myvar2'] = $variablevalue2;
```

please see the below statement

```
public function generateTemplate($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo)
    {
        $template =  $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($this->temp_id)
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, /* here you can defile area and
                                                                                 store of template for which you prepare it */
                        'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars($emailTemplateVariables)
                ->setFrom($senderInfo)
                ->addTo($receiverInfo['email'],$receiverInfo['name']);
        return $this;        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way**


*Some of the functionalities in Magento 2.3.x is different from previous version.

The reason is that in most cases the 2.3.x framework uses Zend Framework 2 (ZF2) and almost totally refuses to applyZend Framework 1 (ZF1).*

> **Magento\Framework\Mail\MailMessageInterface::createAttachment()**

*So, due to this, the previous method  is deprecated and there is no direct method to do so. 

As createAttachment() method is no more available, we will override **Magento\Framework\Mail\Message** and create a class which will implement **Magento\Framework\Mail\MailMessageInterface**.*

**[vendor_name] / [Module_name] /Mail**
***Message.php***

```
<?php

namespace [vendor_name]\[Module_name]\Mail;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\MailMessageInterface;
use Zend\Mail\MessageFactory as MailMessageFactory;
use Zend\Mime\MessageFactory as MimeMessageFactory;
use Zend\Mime\Mime;
use Zend\Mime\Part;
use Zend\Mime\PartFactory;


class Message implements MailMessageInterface
{
    protected $partFactory;
    protected $mimeMessageFactory;
    private $zendMessage;
    private $messageType = self::TYPE_TEXT;
    protected $parts = [];

    public function __construct(PartFactory $partFactory, MimeMessageFactory $mimeMessageFactory, $charset = 'utf-8')
    {
        $this->partFactory = $partFactory;
        $this->mimeMessageFactory = $mimeMessageFactory;
        $this->zendMessage = MailMessageFactory::getInstance();
        $this->zendMessage->setEncoding($charset);
    }
    public function setBodyText($content)
    {
        $this->setMessageType(self::TYPE_TEXT);
        $textPart = $this->partFactory->create();

        $textPart->setContent($content)
            ->setType(Mime::TYPE_TEXT)
            ->setCharset($this->zendMessage->getEncoding());

        $this->parts[] = $textPart;

        return $this;
    }
    public function setBodyHtml($content)
    {
        $this->setMessageType(self::TYPE_HTML);
        $htmlPart = $this->partFactory->create();

        $htmlPart->setContent($content)
            ->setType(Mime::TYPE_HTML)
            ->setCharset($this->zendMessage->getEncoding());

        $this->parts[] = $htmlPart;

        $mimeMessage = new \Zend\Mime\Message();
        $mimeMessage->addPart($htmlPart);
        $this->zendMessage->setBody($mimeMessage);

        return $this;
    }
    public function setBodyAttachment($content, $fileName, $fileType, $encoding = '8bit')
    {
        $attachmentPart = $this->partFactory->create();

        $attachmentPart->setContent($content)
            ->setType($fileType)
            ->setFileName($fileName)
            ->setDisposition(Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT)
            ->setEncoding($encoding);

        $this->parts[] = $attachmentPart;

        return $this;
    }
    public function setPartsToBody()
    {
        $mimeMessage = $this->mimeMessageFactory->create();
        $mimeMessage->setParts($this->parts);
        $this->zendMessage->setBody($mimeMessage);

        return $this;
    }
    public function setBody($body)
    {
        if (is_string($body) && $this->messageType === self::TYPE_HTML) {
            $body = self::createHtmlMimeFromString($body);
        }
        $this->zendMessage->setBody($body);

        return $this;
    }
    public function setSubject($subject)
    {
        $this->zendMessage->setSubject($subject);

        return $this;
    }
    public function getSubject()
    {
        return $this->zendMessage->getSubject();
    }
    public function getBody()
    {
        return $this->zendMessage->getBody();
    }
    public function setFrom($fromAddress)
    {
        $this->setFromAddress($fromAddress, null);

        return $this;
    }
    public function setFromAddress($fromAddress, $fromName = null)
    {
        $this->zendMessage->setFrom($fromAddress, $fromName);

        return $this;
    }
    public function addTo($toAddress)
    {
        $this->zendMessage->addTo($toAddress);

        return $this;
    }
    public function addCc($ccAddress)
    {
        $this->zendMessage->addCc($ccAddress);

        return $this;
    }
    public function addBcc($bccAddress)
    {
        $this->zendMessage->addBcc($bccAddress);

        return $this;
    }
    public function setReplyTo($replyToAddress)
    {
        $this->zendMessage->setReplyTo($replyToAddress);

        return $this;
    }
    public function getRawMessage()
    {
        return $this->zendMessage->toString();
    }
    private function createHtmlMimeFromString($htmlBody)
    {
        $htmlPart = new Part($htmlBody);
        $htmlPart->setCharset($this->zendMessage->getEncoding());
        $htmlPart->setType(Mime::TYPE_HTML);
        $mimeMessage = new \Zend\Mime\Message();
        $mimeMessage->addPart($htmlPart);

        return $mimeMessage;
    }
    public function setMessageType($type)
    {
        $this->messageType = $type;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

After implementation of the **Mail\Message** class we need to extend the **\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder** class.
 This class is used for building the **\Magento\Framework\Mail\Transport** class which is in turn used for email sending.

**[Vendor_name] / [Module_name] /Model/Mail/Template**

***AddEmailAttachemnt.php***

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor_name]\[module_name]\Model\Mail\Template;

class AddEmailAttachemnt extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{

    public function addAttachment($file_content,$file_name,$file_type) 
    {
        $encoding = \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
        $this->message->setBodyAttachment($file_content, $file_name, $file_type, $encoding);
        return $this;
    }
    protected function prepareMessage()
    {
        parent::prepareMessage();
        $this->message->setPartsToBody();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

*Here value of Function Parameter*


                        **$file_content**

```
$file_url = "Exiting File URL (WEB-URL)";
$file_content = file_get_contents($file_url);
```

**$file_name**

    this is name of file with extension like we have PDF file so name is **FileName.pdf**

**$file_type**

There are many File type for Different Files here are some File type list

```
'txt'  => 'text/plain',
'pdf'  => 'application/pdf',
'png' => 'image/png'
```

[Click Here to More File Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type)

**$encoding**

*here is Encoding type value of File on Internet if you are not pass this argument by default is 6-bit Encoding is apply. this value is depends on your file.*

**Now you Have to add below Lines to your di.xml file which are call your Overwrite files.**

**[vendor_name] / [Module_name] / etc**

***di.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

   <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" type="[Vendor_name]\[module_name]\Model\Mail\Template\AddEmailAttachemnt" />

   <preference for="Magento\Framework\Mail\Message" type="[Vendor_name]\[module_name]\Mail\Message"/>

</config>
```

**so now all file are place properly so now we will use send Email Attechment**

**Add this Code to send Email With Attechment**

```
protected $_transportBuilder;

 public function __construct(
        ...................................................................
        ...................................................................
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        ....................................................................
        ....................................................................
   ) {
       .................................
       .................................
       $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
      ..................................... 
      .....................................
   }
   public function execute() {

        ...........................
        ...........................
        ...........................

         $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($Email_template_name) // put Email Template Name
              ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store]) // $store is Current Store Name 
              ->setTemplateVars(
                    [
                       'var_1' => 'value_1',
                       'var_2' => 'value_2',
                       'var_3'    => 'value_3'
                    ]
                  )
              ->setFrom('Sender@gamil.com') // Sender Email address
              ->addTo('Receiver@gmail.com') // Receiver Email Address
              ->addAttachment($file_content, $file_name, $extension) // here Addtement are add with Email
              ->getTransport();
          $transport->sendMessage();

        ............................
        ............................
        ............................
   }
```

Now All code are Place at the Right place now run This Command

```
php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:s:d -f

php bin/magento c:c

php bin/magento c:f
```

*Now check your Receiver Email address attachment*

**Update in Magento [2.3.3]**

Mangento 2.3.3 release introduces a new, immutable **EmailMessageInterface** that supports the sending of multi-part MIME-type content in email.

The Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder and Magento\Newsletter\Model\Queue\TransportBuilder structures were refactored to use this new EmailMessageInterface instead of MessageInterface, which was previously used.
If you are a Magento extension developer and rely on \Magento\Email\Model\Transport::getMessage() or \Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface::getMessage(), those methods will now return the new EmailMessageInterface.

Here add below Lines to your di.xml file which are call your Overwrite files.

**[vendor_name] / [Module_name] / etc**

***di.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

   <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" type="[Vendor_name]\[module_name]\Model\Mail\Template\AddEmailAttachemnt" />


</config>
```

**[Vendor_name] / [Module_name] /Model/Mail/Template**

***AddEmailAttachemnt.php***

```
<?php
declare (strict_types = 1);

namespace [Vendor_name]\[module_name]\Model\Mail\Template;

use Magento\Framework\App\TemplateTypesInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\AddressConverter;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessageInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeMessageInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MimePartInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\FactoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\SenderResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Zend\Mime\Mime;
use Zend\Mime\PartFactory;

class AddEmailAttachemnt extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{

    protected $templateIdentifier;
    protected $templateModel;
    protected $templateVars;
    protected $templateOptions;
    protected $transport;
    protected $templateFactory;
    protected $objectManager;
    protected $message;
    protected $_senderResolver;
    protected $mailTransportFactory;
    private $messageData = [];
    private $emailMessageInterfaceFactory;
    private $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory;
    private $mimePartInterfaceFactory;
    private $addressConverter;
    protected $attachments = [];
    protected $partFactory;

    public function __construct(
        FactoryInterface $templateFactory,
        MessageInterface $message,
        SenderResolverInterface $senderResolver,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        TransportInterfaceFactory $mailTransportFactory,
        MessageInterfaceFactory $messageFactory = null,
        EmailMessageInterfaceFactory $emailMessageInterfaceFactory = null,
        MimeMessageInterfaceFactory $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory = null,
        MimePartInterfaceFactory $mimePartInterfaceFactory = null,
        AddressConverter $addressConverter = null
    ) {
        $this->templateFactory = $templateFactory;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_senderResolver = $senderResolver;
        $this->mailTransportFactory = $mailTransportFactory;
        $this->emailMessageInterfaceFactory = $emailMessageInterfaceFactory ?: $this->objectManager
            ->get(EmailMessageInterfaceFactory::class);
        $this->mimeMessageInterfaceFactory = $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory ?: $this->objectManager
            ->get(MimeMessageInterfaceFactory::class);
        $this->mimePartInterfaceFactory = $mimePartInterfaceFactory ?: $this->objectManager
            ->get(MimePartInterfaceFactory::class);
        $this->addressConverter = $addressConverter ?: $this->objectManager
            ->get(AddressConverter::class);
        $this->partFactory = $objectManager->get(PartFactory::class);
        parent::__construct(
            $templateFactory,
            $message,
            $senderResolver,
            $objectManager,
            $mailTransportFactory,
            $messageFactory,
            $emailMessageInterfaceFactory,
            $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory,
            $mimePartInterfaceFactory,
            $addressConverter
        );
    }
    public function addCc($address, $name = '')
    {
        $this->addAddressByType('cc', $address, $name);

        return $this;
    }
    public function addTo($address, $name = '')
    {
        $this->addAddressByType('to', $address, $name);

        return $this;
    }
    public function addBcc($address)
    {
        $this->addAddressByType('bcc', $address);

        return $this;
    }
    public function setReplyTo($email, $name = null)
    {
        $this->addAddressByType('replyTo', $email, $name);

        return $this;
    }
    public function setFrom($from)
    {
        return $this->setFromByScope($from);
    }
    public function setFromByScope($from, $scopeId = null)
    {
        $result = $this->_senderResolver->resolve($from, $scopeId);
        $this->addAddressByType('from', $result['email'], $result['name']);

        return $this;
    }
    public function setTemplateIdentifier($templateIdentifier)
    {
        $this->templateIdentifier = $templateIdentifier;

        return $this;
    }
    public function setTemplateModel($templateModel)
    {
        $this->templateModel = $templateModel;
        return $this;
    }
    public function setTemplateVars($templateVars)
    {
        $this->templateVars = $templateVars;

        return $this;
    }
    public function setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
    {
        $this->templateOptions = $templateOptions;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getTransport()
    {
        try {
            $this->prepareMessage();
            $mailTransport = $this->mailTransportFactory->create(['message' => clone $this->message]);
        } finally {
            $this->reset();
        }

        return $mailTransport;
    }
    protected function reset()
    {
        $this->messageData = [];
        $this->templateIdentifier = null;
        $this->templateVars = null;
        $this->templateOptions = null;
        return $this;
    }
    protected function getTemplate()
    {
        return $this->templateFactory->get($this->templateIdentifier, $this->templateModel)
            ->setVars($this->templateVars)
            ->setOptions($this->templateOptions);
    }
    protected function prepareMessage()
    {
        $template = $this->getTemplate();
        $content = $template->processTemplate();
        switch ($template->getType()) {
            case TemplateTypesInterface::TYPE_TEXT:
                $part['type'] = MimeInterface::TYPE_TEXT;
                break;

            case TemplateTypesInterface::TYPE_HTML:
                $part['type'] = MimeInterface::TYPE_HTML;
                break;

            default:
                throw new LocalizedException(
                    new Phrase('Unknown template type')
                );
        }
        $mimePart = $this->mimePartInterfaceFactory->create(['content' => $content]);
        $parts = count($this->attachments) ? array_merge([$mimePart], $this->attachments) : [$mimePart];
        $this->messageData['body'] = $this->mimeMessageInterfaceFactory->create(
            ['parts' => $parts]
        );

        $this->messageData['subject'] = html_entity_decode(
            (string) $template->getSubject(),
            ENT_QUOTES
        );
        $this->message = $this->emailMessageInterfaceFactory->create($this->messageData);

        return $this;
    }
    private function addAddressByType($addressType, $email, $name = null): void
    {
        if (is_string($email)) {
            $this->messageData[$addressType][] = $this->addressConverter->convert($email, $name);
            return;
        }
        $convertedAddressArray = $this->addressConverter->convertMany($email);
        if (isset($this->messageData[$addressType])) {
            $this->messageData[$addressType] = array_merge(
                $this->messageData[$addressType],
                $convertedAddressArray
            );
        }
    }
    public function addAttachment($content, $fileName, $fileType)
    {
        $attachmentPart = $this->partFactory->create();
        $attachmentPart->setContent($content)
            ->setType($fileType)
            ->setFileName($fileName)
            ->setDisposition(Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT)
            ->setEncoding(Mime::ENCODING_BASE64);
        $this->attachments[] = $attachmentPart;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Add this Code to send Email With Attechment**

```
protected $_transportBuilder;

 public function __construct(
        ...................................................................
        ...................................................................
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        ....................................................................
        ....................................................................
   ) {
       .................................
       .................................
       $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
      ..................................... 
      .....................................
   }
   public function execute() {

        ...........................
        ...........................
        ...........................

         $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($Email_template_name) // put Email Template Name
              ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store]) // $store is Current Store Name 
              ->setTemplateVars(
                    [
                       'var_1' => 'value_1',
                       'var_2' => 'value_2',
                       'var_3'    => 'value_3'
                    ]
                  )
              ->setFrom('Sender@gamil.com') // Sender Email address
              ->addTo('Receiver@gmail.com') // Receiver Email Address
              ->addAttachment($file_content, $file_name, $extension) // here Addtement are add with Email
              ->getTransport();
          $transport->sendMessage();

        ............................
        ............................
        ............................
   }
```

Now All code are Place at the Right place now run This Command

```
php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:s:d -f

php bin/magento c:c

php bin/magento c:f
```

*Now check your Receiver Email address for attachment*

***I Hope This Helps You.***